# What's new for no more varchar(255)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, varchar

I'm dealing with an old project, when I see there are tips "no more than 200 characters" (in Chinese), but the guy sets a column `varchar(255)`, it is obviously not right (it can only keep 255/3 length Chinese in UTF-8).

It is year 2016 (I mean old times gone, the `varchar(255)` definition rule should be broken), I saw MySQL supports setting varchar length to more than 255 characters. That is great!

But I'm not sure if other database engines like pgSQL or even MS SQL Server (though I never tried that), and what does the SQL standard say about it?

Can we break the `varchar(255)` rule?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what limit you're talking about, since each database vendor has different column width constraints that may be further affected by 3rd party libraries or the project that uses them.  200 characters sounds far more like a 3rd party or project specific limit

Comment: there is no downside to `create table t19
( thing varchar(21000) not null
)engine=innodb charset=utf8;

` and using 500 of it, mysql

Comment: What about other DBMS? And the iso standard said? Cause i didn't find such topic in pgsql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: @Drew: the downside is running up against the row size limit (with multiple columns defined that way), Another downside is the amount of memory that has to be allocated when a resultset is produced, MySQL allocates the maximum length of the row.

Comment: @spencer7593 that's good to know. Never read that before.

Comment: The MEMORY storage engine (used by MySQL for intermediate results, up to max_heap_table_size) uses a fixed row format, a VARCHAR effectively becomes a CHAR.  With longer VARCHAR column, that's fewer rows before the MEMORY table spills to disk using the MyISAM engine.  This is one reason not to declare VARCHAR columns longer than they need to be.  (I believe Percona addressed that, as a performance improvement, introducing a dynamic row format for the MEMORY engine.) https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/flexibility/improved_memory_engine.html

Comment: @spencer7593 that is really far away from my topic...it is rare to use MyISAM nowadays, even not mension to memory storage engine (at least for me). I still want to know other DBMS and the standard.

Comment: @Yarco: My comment was in response to Drew's comment: that there is no downside to declaring a column VARCHAR(21000). MySQL uses the MEMORY and MyISAM storage engines for internal temporary tables  tables.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html   An increase in the maximum length of a VARCHAR column can impact memory usage and performance.  (The usage of the MEMORY and MyISAM storage engines aren't as rare as you make it out to be. Even if all of your tables are InnoDB, MySQL is internally using the MEMORY and MyISAM storage engines.).

Comment: Yeah if someone says something stupid best to point it out. When we use derived tables in subqueries 90% of the time they hits TEMPS at least prior to 5.7

Comment: The row size limit is not the point...i think, cause if that is reason, you create 10000 columns of `varchar(255)`, it will still break the limitation. So it seems ok to use `varchar(1000)` in mysql now....Next topic: other DBMS and the standard? (so i don't have to worry about it can be only used in mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "VARCHAR(255) rule" are you referring to?

Each database vendor is free to implement VARCHAR however they want to. The rules (and guidelines) for VARCHAR isn't necessarily going to be the same for every databsase.

As far as the SQL standard, I haven't really looked into it. It might be pretty loose, so all the VARCHAR implementations are all found to comply with the standard. If the SQL standard for VARCHAR is really strict, then DBMS vendors may either extend the standard, or just may not be compliant. I don't think the actual standard matters all the much. What matters is the actual rules enforced by the DBMS.

As far as a general guideline, specify a VARCHAR length long enough to support the system requirements. If the requirement of the  system is to allow no more than 200 characters, then I'd specify the length as `VARCHAR(200)`.

As another general guideline, don't define VARCHAR lengths that that are larger than they need to be. VARCHAR columns declared longer than necessary can have an impact on resources and performance.

Oracle limit for VARCHAR length is 4000 characters. (In previous versions of Oracle, the maximum was 2000. If you need more than 4000 characters, then you could use `CLOB` datatype.

SQL Server limit to `VARCHAR(8000)`, unless you specify `VARCHAR(MAX)` which allows a maximum size (in bytes) of 2^32-1.

MySQL has limit of 65,535 for maximum row length limit. So that effectively limits size of VARCHAR to VARCHAR(21844), if using a multibyte characterset like utf8.  With a single byte characterset (like latin1), the maximum would be VARCHAR(65532).  If you need more characters than that, or you run into the limit on the maximum row length, you could use TEXT datatype instead of VARCHAR.

---

Most DBMS VARCHAR implementations store a "length" field for a VARCHAR column, along with the value. the length is stored as an integer.

In some DBMS, if the maximum length (in bytes) of a VARCHAR column doesn't exceed 255 bytes, the length field can be implemented as a single byte integer.  If the column allows more than 255 bytes, then the length field has to be larger than a single byte.

---

With dynamic row formats, in terms of row storage, storing 10 characters in a column, it doesn't really matter if the column is defined as VARCHAR(30) or VARCHAR(1000). With fixed row formats, the space for the maximum length of the column will be reserved. The format for row storags is going to depend on the DBMS, and in some cases (MySQL) on the storage engine and the specified row format.

Yes, it's 2016. And we've come a long way since the introduction of the first commercial relational database system.

The database is only one part of the system. There may be limits in the application or other software components.  (If the application is written in C, and the application is defining a structure with a byte array for the field, the limit on the size there is going to be important. Increasing the size allowed in the database won't automatically fix the application.

There could also be length limits/restrictions in Javascript code, or in HTML   elements of a web page. Or there can be limitations of other software components. For example, some of the really old SQL Server ODBC drivers have a limit of 255 characters (bytes?) for both CHAR and VARCHAR columns.

So the length of a VARCHAR in the database is only part of the story.

---

With all of that said, I'm still not clear what you mean, when you ask

Can we break the VARCHAR(255) rule?

I'm wondering what "rule" you are referring to. In most every database I'm aware of, it's possible to define VARCHAR columns much longer than 255 bytes, or 255 characters. And doing that doesn't break any rule.

Comment: It is common to see that other guys to define the varchar in 255 length, that becomes the rule. When you type `varchar(` in google search, it will automatically show you `varchar(255)` option. So it is common, as those commented out my question known. Maybe i do quite often in mysql, so when i define something (the column), there's already a rule for varchar (255 max). Maybe others don't have this, i do.

Comment: So when you say "rule", what you are really referring to is a "convention". I think the primary reasons for the convention is 1) history and 2) old habits die hard. And 255 is still a strict limit on the length VARCHAR for older versions of MySQL (3.23, 4.0).  The 255 is also a strict limit on the Pascal short string datatype. And for C programs that declare a 256 byte character arrays to hold a string. And so on.

Comment: Yes, i think so. But as a Chinese i can not distinguish the two (convention  & rule) cause they are mapping to one Chinese meaning. And It is good news to me, at least when focus only in database & modern times, i should forget 255 limits, and free my soul.